# Does anybody know why i'm getting "error: class, interface, or enum expected"?

Tags: class, interface, enums, jcreator

i'm making a simple class in JCreator and i'm not sure why i'm getting the "error: class interface, or enum expected". This is my code:

```
    public int class javatest 
    {

        public javatest() 
        {
            double coin=168.22;
            int quarter=0;
            int dime=0;
            int nickel=0;
            if (coin>.25)
            {
            coin-=.25;
            quarter++;
            return coin;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: You have an illegal token before the `class` keyword. Remove `int`

Answer (score 0):

Change

`public int class javatest {....`

to

`public class javatest {`